# Same Pandas Data Frames are different in size

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filesystems, pickle, hdf5

I have two data frames A & B saved as pickles, on both Computer 1 (running Ubuntu) and 2 (running MacOSX)

I merge A & B into Data Frame C and save it as X.h5 (HDF format, on both Computers)

However, X.h5 in Computer 1 has smaller size (188MB) than X.h5 in Computer 2 (196MB). I copied X.h5 from Computer 1 to Computer 2, they are still different in size (and also in binary files). But when I use pandas to read both of them, *X_h5_computer1.equals(X_h5_computer2) return **True***

Why it happened? The size difference is significant.

Thank you

Comment: What version of python and pandas do you have on Computer 1 and Computer 2?

Comment: @ Anna Iliukovich-Strakovskaia: on both machines:

Python: 3.5.2 &
Pandas: 0.23.4